# Best looking color from list

Tags: php, image, colors

I have a list of colors extracted from an image (with http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract) and I want to pick the most vivid one (if I have a grey and a light blue, prefer the light blue, for example), to use it as a page background.

For example, for this image:

[image: a festival poster]

I have this colors:

[image]

I would like to get the #3195ab color, which is not the most dominant color, but which is more vivid.

What formulas could I use to determine it?

Comment: you could count the amount of colors and select the color that occurs the most and the set it as the background. As for your other question "is there any PHP script for that" well its possible through php but youll have to do a little good ol fashioned research

Comment: What have you already done? Stackoverflow is no code writing service. Please show us what you have and where your problem is.

Comment: @Seb I have a list of colors extracted with http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract and I need to pick the most vivid one. I updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Use HSL representation of the color and check the value of the Saturation and Light, the higher the saturation the better, and light should be probably at 50%:

http://hslpicker.com/#00f2ff

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out, thanks to @ceyquem!

Here's my code :

```
<?php   
// extracting picture colors using http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract
$GetMostCommonColors = new GetMostCommonColors();
$filename = 'picture.jpg';
$colors = $GetMostCommonColors->Get_Color($filename);

$array_by_score = array();

// calculating image score with this parameters : saturation * diff from nice light (50%)
foreach ($colors as $color => $quantity) {
    $hsl = $GetMostCommonColors::hexToHsl($color);

    $dist_from_light = $hsl['L'] - 0.5;

    $array_by_score[$hsl['S'] * (1 - $dist_from_light).' '][] = $color;
}

// getting best result
ksort($array_by_score);
$best_colors = end($array_by_score);

// here is the best color
$best = end($best_colors);
```

It's easy to adjust to other languages and it's working quite well. I'll maybe have to adjust parameters, but results are good!